# Creating overlayMaps by querying Carto dataset using geoJson

Tags: carto, geojson

I am trying to create an overlayMap by querying a Carto dataset using geoJson.

So far I have:

```
    var baseMaps = {
        "OSM B&W" : OpenStreetMap_BlackAndWhite,
        "Toner" : Stamen_Toner,
        "Relief Map": Stamen_TopOSMRelief, 
        "Satellite Imagery": Esri_WorldImagery
    };

    var geojsonFeature = "http://sspradli.carto.com/api/v2/sql?      format=GeoJSON&q={SELECT * FROM mosquitosamplingsites";   

    var bicycleRental = L.geoJson(bicycleRental).bindPopup('Mosquito trap site');

    var overlayMaps={
    "Mosquito Sampling Sites": bicycleRental
    };              

  L.control.layers(baseMaps,overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

[You can view results here](https://jsbin.com/qofoves/edit?html,output)

Comment: What is your issue, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems with your jsbin code.

1. You are not including Carto.js, instead you are using regular
   Leaflet
2. You are not using the Carto SQL API to get geojson, which
   would look something this:

   ```
   var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'examples', format: 'geojson' });

   // create the layer and add to the map, then will be filled with data
   var countriesLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
   sql.execute("SELECT * FROM european_countries_e").done(function(geojson) {
       countriesLayer.addData(geojson);
   });
   ```

Maybe have a look at some of the [Carto docs and tutorials](https://carto.com/learn/guides)?